# How to Freeze upper section when scrolling down?

Tags: html, css

Hi Can I freeze the upper section of the screen : the first row in the screen with the inputs and button and first header of the table, so both will be freezed when scrolling.

This is the part I want to freeze:

```
<input>input1</input>
<input>input2</input>
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
<button>C</button>
<button>D</button>
<table>
<tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th><th>header4</th><th>header5</th></tr>
```

Can you please apply solution on the follwing jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BRK2c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position: fixed as the demo show : http://jsfiddle.net/BRK2c/4/

```
.upper{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background: #c9c9c9;   
    display: block;

}
```

The header of the table example scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/BRK2c/5/

Comment: I want also the first row of the table remain static

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `position:sticky` to the elements you want to freeze. That will glue them to the specified position in their container until it is completely out of view. Something like:

```css
.sticky-top-0 { 
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

And add a div having that class containing the form elements:

```html
<div class="sticky-top-0">
  <input>input1</input>
  <input>input2</input>
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>C</button>
  <button>D</button>
</div>
<table>
...
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work by itself, because .upper class is from another answer.

Comment: @stramin While this answer could use a description of what it does and how it does it, it adds something to the question (i.e. using `sticky` instead if `fixed`).

Comment: @MoritzRingler, it is true, but it adds something to the `.upper` rule, which is shown in a fiddle in another answer (by SaidbakR), so this answer is not an answer by itself.

Comment: @stramin The name of the CSS class is not important to the answer though, is it? Might be a better answer without it, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @MoritzRingler, that class name it is important, you need to know where the tag goes in the DOM, this class goes in a new tag not included either the question or the answer, it is a new div existing in that jsFiddle only, so, users need to check that other answer before understanding what this answer wanted to add.

Comment: @stramin The point is that this is an honest attempt to answer the question, it is unique and it even works. It should have a description, the rest is fine. At worst, this is a partial answer. Have a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue), maybe it helps to understand what I mean.

Comment: @stramin There, fixed. Wasn't even hard. See what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that section to remain static when scrolling you could do position fixed to that tag or add a class to it then target thet class

Answer (score 0):

How does this suit you:

http://jsfiddle.net/gxRC9/76/

I have used the

```
postion: fixed
```

to keep it in one place and the JQuery ensures that this fixed position is used at the point of scrolling.